# HERE Map not rendering

Tags: here-api

I'm not sure what's wrong, but after setting up the map, all I get is a light blue screen.   Changing schemes seems to not affect it either.  Neither does changing the geoCenter  (currently testing with:  37.73088189776775   -122.14045649405767) which is in the SF bay area.

Also, when I check usage on the project via my account, it is 0 despite me testing all day.

My delegate is called when I try to scroll the map, so I know that part is hooked up and I'm actually rendering the map.  It's just a light blue screen...like I'm stuck in the ocean...

Any ideas?  Any low hanging fruit I can check?  Thanks.

Update:  I'm using the iOS Starter SDK.  Please let me know what additional information would help.  Thanks.

Comment: HERE provides different APIs or SDKs. Can you please provide some more details about your map integration?

Comment: I'm using the iOS Starter SDK. Please let me know what additional information would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by not embedding the map inside another view.  By bringing it to the top level, and then subclassing it I was able to get it to work.  Thanks.